# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string Maatwebsite

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I was trying to export a query - the function in the controller was as below

```
class Export implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $data = DB::table('Providers')->get();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

but producing the error:

> vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php

[image]

> "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: Please show some of the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Hello @Camilo I updated the post, thaks for you comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a collection out of it and then map it.

```
$dataArray = collect($data)->map( function($stdClass) {

    return (array) stdClass;
}
```

Not sure what your data looks like, perhaps you could also cast it to a string.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Export implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $data = DB::table('Providers')->get();
        $data = $data->toArray();
        $data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You Can Do It Like This

```
class Export implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $data = DB::table('Providers')->get();
        return $data->toJson();
        return $data->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kayle Liu, but I had the error: `Call to a member function each() on array` in `public function fromCollection(FromCollection $sheetExport, Worksheet $worksheet)
    {
        $sheetExport
            ->collection()
            ->each(function ($row) use ($sheetExport, $worksheet) {
                $this->appendRow($row, $sheetExport);
            });
    }` in `vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Sheet.php`

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to do, but that 2nd return is never called. And even then, it's expecting a `Collection`, so converting this to `json` or an array is pointless...